# Javascript - option text vs innerHTML

Tags: javascript, text, innerhtml

```js
var option = document.getElementById("o");
option.text = "B";
```

```html
<option id="o">A</option>
```

I want to change the text of an `option` tag with `javascript`. For this, I use the `text` property like above but the same result is also applied if I use the `innerHTML` property. Which one should I choose? Thanks

Comment: In this case as you don't need any html to insert `text` should work for you.

Comment: I can't see how the linked dup answers the question ..? [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) says: "_Permitted content: Text, possibly with escaped characters (like \&eacute;)._", `option` element can't contain HTML, hence it's not useful to set non-standard property, stick to [`text`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmloptionelement), it works with all browsers.